# Opening a browser from Java code is taking a lot of time

Tags: java, browser

I am opening a default Browser in my Java code. It takes 5-10 sec to open. Is there any way to open Browser faster. I am using the below code to open the browser.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + url);
```

Also to add, when the browser is opened manually there is no such delay. The main class calls another class obj which opens the browser.

Opening a browser from a terminal using `xdg-open` only took 2-3 seconds.

Comment: When you open a browser manually, how long does it take to open?

Comment: Does `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + url);` work any faster?

Comment: I tried opening browser from terminal using xdg-open, it took 2-3 sec but still was faster than the java code.

Comment: The best questions also teach (and also tend to get upvotes). For example, I had no idea that `xdg-open` existed before your question. So, always include the steps that you've already tried when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe call the default browser:

```
try {
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.browse(  new URI("http://google.com/") );
} catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it is working better in half time I would say, Thanks!!